# Flutter - where to refresh list from API based on user text input

Tags: flutter, dart

Attempting to create a "filter as the user types" list.

I have "parent" widget (screen) that has a

1. text field and a
2. "custom widget" class defined in a separate file [composed of `State` object and `StatefulWidget`] that basically calls an API with a `FutureBuilder` and builds a ListView with the result.  When the screen first launches, the "custom widget" uses `initState()` to make the async call that the FutureBuilder relies on.  this is working perfectly and shows the list unfiltered.

Ultimately, I want to use the text field in the "parent" widget to filter results from the API in the custom widget.  So, I need a way of having the custom widget "receive" or "detect" the value of the text field and then include that value as a `GET` parameter to the API (for filtering on server side).  I can get it to work where the text field is passed to the custom widget as a parameter and is accessible to the State object (via `widget.fieldName`).

The problem is that `initState()` is only called once.  So I cannot use it to make additional calls to the API as the user types.  I know that `build()` gets called every time the text field changes (because it's a parameter to the statefulwidget).  However, I can't use `build()` to call the async function since build() must return a widget.  Calling the async function and then returning a blank/placeholder widget isn't an option since the list originally pre-filled (in `initState()`) with no filter, so I don't want the list to disappear while the API refresh happens.  Also, I don't think this is what `build()` was meant for (it should be "pure" which i read as dumb and simply reflect the results of state management that is handled elsewhere).

I was looking for something "between" `initState()` and `build()` that gets called every time, but isn't actually part of drawing the UI like `build()` is.  I know about `didChangeDependencies()`, but that doesn't get called.  It seems I would have to setup some type of `"Inherited Widget"` system that I'm not familiar with.

Any ideas how to accomplish what I'm looking for?  I guess I could theoretically move the text field into the "custom widget" class and see if I can use the closer scope of the two to affect each other (for instance i could use the TextField's `onChanged()` to directly call the async function that the FutureBuilder relies on (since they are in the same class it would have access to it).  However, I would like to keep them separate since in the future there could be a bunch of things I would need/want to pass to the custom widget for filtering (GPS location/other preferences) and trying to include everything in the custom widget class seems clunky (but maybe i'm wrong there).

Thanks in-advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `callback-style` events to communicate between your widgets. (Communication with Flutter using **`VoidCallback`** and **`Function(x)`** )

***Example:***

Here we’ve added a new Function(int) named onCountChange that we’re calling with the value that we want to pass back to the parent.

```
// counter_page.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Count extends StatelessWidget {
  final int count;
  final VoidCallback onCountSelected; // <<<

  final Function(int) onCountChange; //  <<<

  Count({
    @required this.count,
    @required this.onCountChange,
    this.onCountSelected,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            onCountChange(1);
          },
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("$count"),
          onPressed: () => onCountSelected(),
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
          onPressed: () {
            onCountChange(-1);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

> Inside of the parent we’re able to listen to this and change the value
>   of count accordingly

```
class _CounterPageState extends State<CounterPage> {
  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Counter Page")),
      body: Center(
        child: Count(
          count: count,
          onCountSelected: () {//<<< Listen to the onCountSelected callback
            print("Count was selected.");
          },
          onCountChange: (int val) { // <<< return a value back to the parent
            setState(() => count += val);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean like this?

```
Future<String> getPosts() async { //do_something }

_refreshAction() {
    setState(() {
      this.getPosts();
    });
  }


onPressed: () { _refreshAction(); }
```

Comment: the refreshAction() is correct.  the complication comes from the onPressed() part.  which is actually a TextField (which has an onChanged() method).  however, the textfield right now is not in the same class as getPosts() and has no access to it.  the textfield and the "custom widget" class are siblings in the parent screen.  i can pass values from the textfield to the custom widget in it's constructor as a parameter, but i cant use initState() or build().  i'm starting to think an inherited widget is the answer, but it seems so heavy for what i need to do.  thanks!

Comment: @bl4ckck in wrapper class getting error of setState(). as from model class trying to call activity class method.